# select command in smart card and status word

Tags: smartcard, card-reader, applet

I use smart card and I upload different applet on the Smart Card.
**Q1:**When I Select one applet with PyApdu.exe and after select another applet without reset connection with card reader **SW=9000** return. Is it good behavior?

**Q2:** If select applet with PyApdu.exe tools and return **SW=9000** and after this I select another applet that AID there is not in applet list of smart card and return **SW==9000** is it good behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That is bad behavior. Versions of the old Muscle applet are know to do return 90 00 for any AID. Well behaved applet will return an FCI with a 4F tag containing the AID when selected. For example OpenSC added code to check for this bad behavior in several drivers. Find a better applet to load.

Comment: Thanks, If I use select command with AID not in list of applet id, what is Status Word in standard smart card?